# Разные Intent'ы вызывают одну и ту же Activity

Tags: activity, android

Создаю по событию Notification, Intent у оповещения содержит вызов определенной Activity. В Intent я кладу дополнительные данные (putExtra), которые извлекаются в Activity. Проблема заключается в следующем: при клике на оповещение вызывается каждый раз новый экземпляр той же самой Activity, но со старыми данными. По факту имею: несколько одинаковых Activity с одинаковыми данными, но мне не надо несколько одинаковых Activity, хотелось бы в одном экземпляре просто данные обновлять и все. Как осуществить?

Вот как выглядит добавление оповещения(ProcessInfo - Parcelable):

```
private void AddNotification(String title, String message, ProcessInfo processInfo)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(new Date().getTime());
    int NOTIFY_ID = rnd.nextInt();
    int icon = 17301591;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    notification.defaults = notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(mainContext,ProcessActivity.class);

    notifyIntent.putExtra("Process", processInfo);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mainContext, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(mainContext, title, message, contentIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```

ProcessActivity.class:

```
public class ProcessActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView pNameView, pMachineNameView, pTitleView, pStatusView,pStartedSinceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.process);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ProcessInfo process = (ProcessInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra("Process");

    pNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pName);
    pMachineNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pMachineName);
    pTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pTitle);
    pStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pStatus);
    pStartedSinceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pStartedSince);

    pNameView.setText(process.getName());
    pMachineNameView.setText(process.getMachineName());
    pTitleView.setText(process.getWindowTitle());
    pStatusView.setText(process.getStatus());
    pStartedSinceView.setText(process.getStartTime().toString());

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это зависит от параметра `flag` в `PendingIntent.getActivity()`

там 4 разных флага - [почитайте документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), сейчас уже не упомню какая комбинация флагов вам подойдет.

Comment: Подошел FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, но экземпляров Activity по-прежнему несколько создается. Т.е. я жму Back и перехожу по всем ProcessActivity, ранее созданным.

Comment: Вообще судя по доке вам нужен FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: этот флаг тоже самое делает, Activity по-прежнему остаются. хотя я думаю, что может они и должны оставаться, если не были закрыты?

Comment: Там, если память не изменяет, надо комбинировать флаги

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, если не хотите возвращаться к Активити которые закрыли.